# Nested Loops in R based on factor's unique values

Tags: r, nested-loops

I am working with a dataset that contains a factor variable as well as some numeric variables. I would like to create a series of scatter plots for the numerical variables comparing every possible pairing of the numeric factors. So if the factor variable had 4 unique values (A, B, C, D); my script would produce 5plots comparing (A & B, A & C, A & D, B & C, B & D, C & D). It does not matter which variable is on which axis in the scatterplots.

Here is how I intend to process my data:

```
df = read.table("filename", sep="\t", header=TRUE)
samples1 = unique(df$Sample_ID)
s.len = length(samples1)
samples2 = samples1[2:s.len]
```

This leaves me with two ordered lists which I can loop through using something like:

```
FOREACH (samples1) {
  df1 = df[df$Sample_ID == "samples1", ]
  FOREACH (sample2) {
    df2 = df[df$Sample_ID == "samples2", ]
    plot(df1$count, df2$count)
 }
}
```

## Note that the above code is not functional

I guess that there is a way to write a functional version of this code either by using apply() or some other, more appropriate function but I am not sure how to do do it. I also have a feeling that there might be a more efficient way to do this than creating new data frames with every iteration of the loop; maybe there is some already existing function for pulling each unique pair from a factor which might grant me a list and the option to achieve the same result with a single loop?

Comment: maybe the `pairs` function. see http://www.r-bloggers.com/scatterplot-matrices-in-r/

Comment: Why are you not comparing C and D?

Comment: It sounds like you may have independent samples, meaning the data is not generated in eg (A,B) pairs. If that is true, I don't think scatter plots would make any sense. You might want a boxplot instead to compare a change in distribution.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a way of doing this without a for-loop, using the base-R function 'combn'. It uses subsetting of the original data, without the need for creating new dataframes. The call to plot also manages labelling of axis and plot title.

```
#generate some data
set.seed(123)
dat <- data.frame(
  count = rbinom(100,5,0.5),
  sample = LETTERS[1:4],
  stringsAsFactors = F
)

#get combinations
my_combs <- combn(unique(dat$sample),2)
# > my_combs
# [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
# [1,] "A"  "A"  "A"  "B"  "B"  "C"
# [2,] "B"  "C"  "D"  "C"  "D"  "D"


par(mfrow = c(3,2))
#plot
apply(my_combs, 2,function(x) {
  plot(
    dat[dat$sample == x[1],"count"], dat[dat$sample == x[2], "count"],
    xlab = x[1],ylab = x[2], main = sprintf("scatterplot of %s and %s",x[1],x[2])
  )
})
```

[image]